# How can I fail the build when heroku container:release is not successful?

Tags: heroku, jenkins-pipeline, heroku-cli

We recently had the issue, that Heroku changed the requirement of how to connect to the Postgres DB and consequently our release failed. Trouble was that the Jenkins build was green, so we never realised that our software update was not live. We build with a Jenkinsfile and I know that the 'sh' step will fail the build if an error code != 0 is returned, so that means that **heroku container:release** always returns exit code 0, even though it logs the error. So how can we let the build fail, if an error ocurrs?

Answer (score 0):

Well, at least I found a workaround:

```
heroku releases --json -n 1 -a play-pac | grep '"succeeded"'
```

It will exit with exit code 1 if the release did not succeed.
Got it from [here](https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/1271)